# Componentes de react no cargan los estilos css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Tengo un par de componentes en react que a la hora de cargar los estilos no los carga. El códeigo del componente es el siguiente:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import './producto.css'

class Producto extends Component {
  render() {
    const producto = this.props.producto
    return(
      <div className='producto'>
        <img className='img' alt={producto.name} src={producto.img}/>
        <p> {producto.name} </p>
        <p> {producto.price}€ </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Producto
```

Y el código css es este:

```
.producto {
    border: '1px solid #eee';
    box-shadow: '0px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    width: '30%';
    padding: '10px 10px';
    border-radius: '5px';
}

.img {
    width: '100%';
}
```

También tengo otro componente con su correspondiente hoja de estilos que tampoco carga.

Edito:
Tanto los dos archivos de los componentes como los dos archivos css están al mismo nivel

Comment: `./producto.css` verificaste si está bien la ruta del css?

Comment: Sí, la ruta está bien. Y los archivos están al mismo nivel.

Comment: Si lo hago de esa manera me da error

Comment: No se mucho de react, pero esta lectura te puede servir: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: No aplica la clase o solo no se ven los cambios? es decir al ver tu **componente** en el navegador, si le das en **inspeccionar elemento** si te muestra `<div class="producto">` o solo te muestra `<div class="">`?

Answer (score 0):

Todo se ve correcto, en teoría no debería dar problemas, intenta recargar la chache de tu navegador o cerrar y abrir el navegador para ver si los cambios no se aplican, en caso de que no verse cambios aplicados checa tu proyecto, algo esta pasando que esta causando error con la importación de tu hoja de estilos. También podrías probar insertando los estilos directamente en el component con style={{}}

Comment: Ya lo he comprobado y todo está bien. He probado a usar los estilos en linea y funciona sin problemas. De esta manera funciona.

`const styles = {
 productos: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  background: 'red'
 }
}

class Productos extends Component {
 render() {
  const { productos, agregarAlCarro } = this.props
  
  return(
   <div style={styles.productos}>
    {productos.map(producto => 
    <Producto
     agregarAlCarro={agregarAlCarro}
     key={producto.name}
     producto={producto}
    />)}

   </div>
  )
 }
}`

Comment: @MoisesMS lo que se me ocurre entonces es que en alguna parte de tu proyecto los estilos de la etiqueta <div> o algún componente con la misma clase esta sobrescribiendo los estilos de CSS.

Comment: El método con el que funciona solo lo hace con la clase productos. En cambio con la clase producto no funciona. No entiendo nada

Comment: @MoisesMS prueba usando la propiedad !important en tus estilos, para intentar forzar que se apliquen tus cambios, recuerda recargar tu navegador eliminando la cache para comprobar 100% que algo mas raro esta ocurriendo.

Comment: También podrías probar importar tus estilos con un modulo de CSS https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y nada. También he probado con los estilos en linea. Pero solo funciona con el componente productos. Con el otro no funciona.

Comment: Inspecciona elemento en el navegador y dinos si vez la clase "producto" en tu div y también dinos que estilos tiene.